# How can I enable OSX 'inverted' scrolling on my keyboard (win7)?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, touchpad, scrolling

I have bought a new keyboard (Logitech k400), and it's trackpad has two finger scroll which works in the 'standard' windows direction (swipe up to scroll up the page). However my laptop's built in touchpad (synaptics driver) has 'inverted' scrolling (swipe up to go down, like on OSX). How can I invert the scrolling? Will I need to install a new/customised driver?

Answer (score 1):

If Windows 7 interprets the trackpad's gesture-scrolling as anything similar to a standard scroll-wheel, you may well find what you're looking for in [Super User question #310681](https://superuser.com/questions/310681/inverting-direction-of-mouse-scroll-wheel). There are a few different answers that you may want to give a run.

Answer (score 1):

The exact setting is specific to the touchpad manufacturer. However, almost all manufacturers provide the option to inverse scrolling.

Here's the setting for Lenovo's ThinkPad laptop.
(screenshots attached)

[image]
<sup>**Steps 3-4 & 8**</sup>

[image]
<sup>**Steps 5-7**</sup>

1. Go to Start Menu -> type Mouse.
2. Click on *Mouse* option under *Control Panel*.
3. In Mouse Properties window, go to last tab named *ThinkPad*. In non-Lenovo laptop, this will be named a Touchpad manufacturer's name (example: Synaptics)
4. Click *Settings* inside the *Gestures* group
5. In the Touchpad properties window, click on *Scrolling* in the left pane.
6. Now in the right pane, select the *Enable reverse scrolling direction*.
7. Click *OK*.
8. Now click *OK* in the Mouse Properties window.
9. Your touchpad scroll is now inverted.

Answer (score -2):

This tool will set or remove the 'flipflopwheel' registry setting in windows for all mouse devices.

Run this exe...
[flipflop-windows-wheel](https://github.com/jamie-pate/flipflop-windows-wheel/blob/master/bin/Debug/FlipWheel.exe)
It works like a charm!

Comment: Pointing to a tool may be a helpful hint, but it doesn't explain how to accomplish a solution to the question.  Please read http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers for guidance on recommending software.

Answer (score -2):

Go to Start Menu>'Change mouse settings'>ELAN/Synaptics tab>Options...

There you are!

Comment: It’s a Logitech wireless keyboard/touchpad combo, nothing Synaptics here.