# Reverse mousewheel scrolling for Windows 8 Store apps

Tags: windows-8, mouse, modern-ui, scrolling

I'm using [this method](https://superuser.com/questions/310681/inverting-direction-of-mouse-scroll-wheel) for inverting the scrolling direction for my mouse. It works perfectly fine in Windows 8 desktop mode.

However, in Windows Store apps, the mouse direction is apparently inverted from the desktop mode. What I'd like to have is both Windows desktop mode *and* Windows Store ("Metro") Apps use the same scrolling direction, rather than opposite.

Does anybody know of a way to do this? Some arcane registry key perhaps?

Comment: the scrolling is hardcoded in the new UI.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is indeed an arcane registry tweak.

Reverse the vertical and horizontal scroll directions:

Hit Windows, type “Regedit” and press Enter/Return
Answer “Yes”, I Know If I Torque Preferences By Hand I Could Break My Computer
Expand the tree on the left side of Regedit through HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, SYSTEM, CurrentControlSet, Enum, HID.
You should see a number of items under HID that start with VID. Expand each of these until you can see each’s Device Parameters… some will have Device Parameters, some will not.
Click each Device Parameters.  If on the right side FlipFlopWheel is shown, double-click FlipFlopWheel, type “1” (without the quotes) in place of “0” and click OK. This fixes vertical panning. Do the same for FlipFlopHScroll if you want horizontal panning au naturel. (I think you’ll like it.)
Restart the computer (Windows + I, Power, Restart.)

Comment: If you look at the link in my original question, I'm already using that method, and it has no affect on Windows Store style apps.