# To reverse the scrolling of Mighty Mouse in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mouse, scrolling, mighty-mouse

I read this [post](http://askabouttech.com/windows-10-change-touchpad-scrolling-direction/) but there is no *Device Settings* in my mouse configurations.

How can you reverse the scrolling of mighty mouse in Windows 10?

Comment: Windows 10 reversed 2-finger scrolling on trackpads and touchscreens. I think you would have to get software from your mouse manufacturer for changes to your mouse wheel behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

First install AutoHotKey. Now create a script that looks like this :

```
$WheelUp::
Send {WheelDown}
Return

$WheelDown::
Send {WheelUp}
Return
```

Save it as a .ahk file and double-click the file to run it. Now you should have inverted the mouse wheel scrolling.

All information from here, though it has been modified with the addition of the $ prefix to prevent the Send commands from being captured again by the script (which exacerbates the MaxHotkeysPerInterval issue)

Add the following to the script to invert horizontal wheel scrolling:

```
$WheelLeft::
Send {WheelRight}
Return

$WheelRight::
Send {WheelLeft}
Return
```

Scrolling with the wheel might exceed the default limit of hotkey presses in a specified time interval. By default, this is 70 hotkey presses (#MaxHotkeysPerInterval) per 2000 milliseconds (#HotkeyInterval). Add this directive to your script to increase the limit from 70 to 200 hotkey presses per interval:

```
#MaxHotkeysPerInterval 200
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think this answer here http://superuser.com/a/364353/2005 is even better than installation of 3rd party software.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [X-Button Mouse Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm) and remap the wheel up and wheel down to their opposites. It will also allow you to remap any buttons to other functions system wide, or per program as desired.