# Mac Inverse Scrolling

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot-camp

how did you do it? I'm on Win 10 Boot-camp. Can you please explain the steps? I have tried entering all those commands into powershell but it would not work. Please could you explain more further?

Comment: What are “all those commands” and where did you find them?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You need to have the bootcamp tray icon app to simply set the inverting behaviour of your wheel or pad.</strike> There is also a workaround via registry

an entry called FlipFlopWheel that does this!

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\HID\VID_???\VID_???\Device Parameters.

In my case it was the first VID ** entry.

be sure to reboot after that.

that helped me in the past:
[Inverting direction of mouse scroll wheel](https://superuser.com/questions/310681/inverting-direction-of-mouse-scroll-wheel)

Comment: It sure would be great if there actually were such an option in Bootcamp. There isn’t, though, so why don’t you tell us about the registry hack?

Comment: apologize....I confused it with the F-key behaviour.... I edit my answer, pointing to the right registry key, which worked fine for me with my MacBookAir 13 from 2011