# Mac BootCamp inverted scroll acceleration

Tags: macbook, touchpad, boot-camp, scrolling

I recently installed Windows 11 on my MacBook Air 2017. I noticed the inverted scroll problem quite quickly and found the solution for [that](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63598/invert-scrolling-on-windows-bootcamp). Something was still bothering me about the acceleration so I tried to move the scroll slowly and then quickly. I found out that when I quickly scroll the page goes almost nowhere, and waaay to fast when I scroll slowly. Is there a fix for this?

TDLR; Page scrolls further when moving fingers slowly.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to undo the registry edit that you did and use instead
the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

To invert the scroll you could use a AutoHotkey script such as:

```
$WheelLeft::
Send {WheelRight}
Return

$WheelRight::
Send {WheelLeft}
Return
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the script in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test.
You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Source:
[Inverting direction of mouse scroll wheel](https://superuser.com/questions/310681/inverting-direction-of-mouse-scroll-wheel).